# Can't close window in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I have this code in my renderer.js:

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
const remote = require('electron').remote;

function sendForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault() // stop the form from submitting
    let code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    ipcRenderer.send('2FacLogin', {twoFactorCode: code});

    // TODO Close Window
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
}
```

this is how the window is opened:

```
 const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
    }
  })
```

Why does the window not close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **Electron 10.0.0**, the `remote` module is disabled by default, it must be explicitly enabled when creating a new browser window by adding `enableRemoteModule: true` to the `webPreferences` object.

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
})
```

See: [Default Changed: enableRemoteModule defaults to false](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#default-changed-enableremotemodule-defaults-to-false)

BTW, the following statement:

```
var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

most certainly triggers an error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentWindow' of undefined

that you can catch yourself by checking the DevTools' console...